# Powershell command to delete everything that starts with _

Tags: powershell, filter

If I use the code:

```
get-wmiObject win32_computersystem | select *
```

I get all the properties that this wmiobject has. I want to filter it, so that all the properties starting with _ (underscore) are filtered out. But I can't find the command to do this.
Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-5.1) instead of Get-WmiObject. If you read the help for [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) you will learn that you can include desired properties and you can exclude properties if you like:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem  | 
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty __* -Property *
```

Comment: Whilst `Get-CimInstance` supercedes `Get-WmiObject`, it doesn't return the same information. E.g. I found that `-Exclude` wasn't needed with `Cim` as it didn't return the properties starting with `__`. Try this: `(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).psobject.Properties.name | where {$_ -notin (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem ).psobject.properties.name}`

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of PowerShell.

From [Select-Object/Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6#parameters), I would try `-ExcludeProperty`

> Specifies the properties that this cmdlet excludes from the operation. Wildcards are permitted.

```
get-wmiObject win32_computersystem | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty _* -Property *
```

Comment: on win7ps5.1 the `-ExcludeProperty` parameter is _ignored_ if you don't also include `-Property` with something to show what you DO want. i usually use `-Property *` for that.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]